# Set all raster values outside of 99 % contour to NA

Tags: raster, r

I am currently working with a very large raster showing Utilization Distribution values of animal tracks. As the raster is very large, there are a lot of 0 values and UD values so small that they are not biologically relevant. In attempt to remove those I am trying to set all value rasters that are outside of the 99 % contour to NA.

Here is an example raster:

```
r <- raster(t(volcano[,ncol(volcano):1]))
```

So, for this example, what I am trying to do is set all values that are outside the 99 % contour to NA so that I then can work with the new/trimmed raster.

Comment: How are you defining the "99% contour"? 99% of what, in this example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential answer:

First extract the max values of your raster:

```
maxR <- r@data@max
```

Store the 99 % of highest values in your raster, i.e. the 99 % contour in a new object:

```
c99 <- maxR*0.01 # 0.01 for 99 %, 0.05 for 95 % etc.
```

Set values outside this range of values to NA:

```
r[r<c99] <- NA
```

Comment: Instead of multiplying 0.01 with max value, use the quantile() to find the required percentile value.

Comment: You asked the question so is this really the anwer, in which case why do you say its a "Potential" answer? Is it right? Does it work for you?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you want to make the values less than 1 percentile as NA in a a raster. Please check the below solution to do the same

```
c99 <- quantile(ras, c(0.01), na.rm = T) # Find the 1 percentile value
ras[ras < c99] <- NA # make the pixels less than this value as NA
```

Comment: Try not to answer questions based on what you think the questioner might be asking - add a comment to the Q asking for clarification and if possible flag the question for closure because it "Needs details or clarity".